# python blank return value from command line

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a simple python file cars.py

```
def Hello():
  print("hi")
def Bye();
  print("Bye")
```

from the command line i cd to the directory where cars is at and i run:
    python cars.py Hello()
nothing returns when i am expecting ("hi")
This is the terminal in pycharm and windows cmd.

I also try to use pycharm's python console i change to the folder that is holding cars.py and try running

```
cars.py Hello()
```

I get an invalid syntax error

```
cars.py Hello()
File "<ipython-input-16-a986b605d7b9>", line 1
cars.py Hello()
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I call this function from a terminal and the python console?

Comment: Call `Hello` inside the .py file and run "python cars.py".

Comment: How can this be run in the python console, in pycharm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanna do this:

```
python -c "from cars import *;Hello()"
```

Output:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Sanchit\PycharmProjects\demo>python -c "from cars import *;Hello()"
hi
```